# Conflict between two buttons. The signout button enters in requiredfieldvalidator, but I don't want that

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I have two buttons, one to ADD=Button1 and one to signout=BtnSingout.

When I push signout it doesn't redirect to my default page. Instead, it enters in required field validation error message.To signout I need to complete all the textboxes.

Also i have an `if` where if I push button Adauga(ADD) and I have a textbox not filled it needs to show me an error in msjadd, but it's doing nothing.  To add info to database I need to complete all the textboxes.

Here is the code in apsx.cs:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int Salar_negociat = 0;
        int Salar_realizat = 0;
        int Vechime = 0;
        int Spor = 0;
        int Premii_brute = 0;
        int Compensatie = 0;
        int Avans = 0;
        int Retineri = 0;

        if (nume.Text == "" || prenume.Text == "" || functie.Text == "" || salar_negociat.Text == ""
        || salar_realizat.Text == "" || vechime.Text == "" || spor.Text == "" || premii_brute.Text == ""
        || compensatie.Text == "" || avans.Text == "" || retineri.Text == "")
        {
            msjadd.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            msjadd.Text = " Exista casute necompletate , va rugam sa le completati";
        }
        else
        {


            Salar_negociat = Convert.ToInt16(salar_negociat.Text);
            Salar_realizat = Convert.ToInt16(salar_realizat.Text);
            Vechime = Convert.ToInt16(vechime.Text);
            Spor = Convert.ToInt16(spor.Text);
            Premii_brute = Convert.ToInt16(premii_brute.Text);
            Compensatie = Convert.ToInt16(compensatie.Text);
            Avans = Convert.ToInt16(avans.Text);
            Retineri = Convert.ToInt16(retineri.Text);

            try
            {

                con.Open();

                strSQL = "insert into angajati (nume,prenume,functie,salar_negociat,salar_realizat,vechime,spor,premii_brute,compensatie,avans,retineri)  values  ('" + nume.Text + "','" + prenume.Text + "','" + functie.Text + "'," + Salar_negociat + "," + Salar_realizat + "," + Vechime + "," + Spor + "," + Premii_brute + "," + Compensatie + "," + Avans + "," + Retineri + ")";

                cm = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, con);
                i = cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                nume.Text = "";
                prenume.Text = "";
                functie.Text = "";
                salar_negociat.Text = "";
                salar_realizat.Text = "";
                vechime.Text = "";
                spor.Text = "";
                premii_brute.Text = "";
                compensatie.Text = "";
                avans.Text = "";
                retineri.Text = "";
                msjadd.Text = "Adăugare cu succes";
            }




            catch (OleDbException ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    con.Close();
            }
        }
    }


    protected void btnSingout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["Username"] = null;
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
}
```

The code in aspx is this :

```
<div class="center-page1">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
           <asp:Label ID="numeangajati"  runat="server" Text="Nume"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="nume" CssClass="form-control" Placeholder="Nume" name="name" runat="server" Title="Introduceți caractere de forma Aa..." data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"  ></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Câmp gol" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="nume"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Nume invalid" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="nume" ValidationExpression="^[A-Z][Za-z]+((\s)?((\'|\-|\.)?([A-Z][Za-z])+))*$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
           <asp:Label ID="Label1"  runat="server" Text="Prenume"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="prenume" placeholder="Prenume" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Câmp gol" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="prenume" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Prenume invalid" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="prenume" ValidationExpression="^[A-Z][Za-z]+((\s)?((\'|\-|\.)?([A-Z][Za-z])+))*$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
           <asp:Label ID="Label2"  runat="server" Text="Functie"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="functie" placeholder="Functie" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Câmp gol" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="functie" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Funcție invalidă" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="functie" ValidationExpression="^[A-Z][Za-z\s]+$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
           <asp:Label ID="Label3"  runat="server" Text="Salar negociat"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="salar_negociat" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Câmp invalid" ControlToValidate="salar_negociat" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator4" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Salar negociat invalid" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="salar_negociat" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]*$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

        </div>
         <div class="col-xs-12">
           <asp:Label ID="Label4"  runat="server" Text="Salar realizat(%)"></asp:Label>
             <asp:TextBox ID="salar_realizat" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
             <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Câmp gol" ControlToValidate="salar_realizat" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
             <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator3" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Salar realizat invalid" Display="Dynamic" MinimumValue="0" MaximumValue="100" ControlToValidate="salar_realizat" Type="Integer"></asp:RangeValidator>
             </div>
         <div class="col-xs-12">
           <asp:Label ID="Label5"  runat="server" Text="Vechime(%)"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="vechime" CssClass="form-control" text="0" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
             <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Câmp gol" ControlToValidate="vechime" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
             <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Vechime invalidă" Type="Integer" MinimumValue="0" MaximumValue="100" ControlToValidate="vechime" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RangeValidator>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
           <asp:Label ID="Label10"  runat="server" Text="Spor(%)"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="spor" CssClass="form-control" text="0" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Câmp gol" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="spor"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator2" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Spor invalid" Type="Integer" MinimumValue="0" MaximumValue="100" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="spor"></asp:RangeValidator>

        </div>
         <div class="col-xs-12">
           <asp:Label ID="Label6"  runat="server" Text="Premii brute"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="premii_brute" CssClass="form-control" runat="server">0</asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator7" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Premii brute invalide" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="premii_brute" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]*$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
             <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator8" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Câmp gol" ControlToValidate="premii_brute" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>


        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
           <asp:Label ID="Label7"  runat="server" Text="Compensatii"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="compensatie" CssClass="form-control" runat="server">0</asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator9" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Câmp gol" ControlToValidate="compensatie" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator8" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Compensații invalide" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="compensatie" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]*$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
           <asp:Label ID="Label8"  runat="server" Text="Avans"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="avans" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator10" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Câmp gol" ControlToValidate="avans" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator6" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Avans invalid" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="avans" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]*$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
           <asp:Label ID="Label9"  runat="server" Text="Retineri"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="retineri" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator11" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Câmp gol" ControlToValidate="retineri" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator5" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Rețineri invalide" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="retineri" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]*$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 space-vert space-bottom-footer">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" class="btn btn-success" runat="server" Text="Adaugare" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            <asp:Label ID="msjadd" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="#33CC33" ></asp:Label>
        </div>

   </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [validation group](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx) for all the RequiredFieldValidators and the add button. example

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" ValidationGroup="AddValidationGroup"  ....
```

and

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6"  ValidationGroup="AddValidationGroup"  ...
```

do the same for all the asp:RequiredFieldValidators

Comment: thank you, works perfect. thank you for your time, have a nice day!